# Why won't my iCloud symlinks for ~/Desktop and ~/Documents show up in Finder?

Tags: icloud, finder, ventura, symlink

### TL;DR

I can't see the symlinks to my iCloud-synced `Desktop` and `Documents` folders in my home directory when using Finder. I have some work-arounds, but want to understand and solve the underlying problem.

### What (Apparently) Caused the Problem

I used the iCloud setting in:

> System Settings -> Apple ID -> iCloud Drive -> Desktop & Documents Folders

for moving my Desktop & Documents folders to iCloud on macOS Ventura. It's a simple toggle within the iCloud settings. It is currently enabled, and had been enabled without similar issues under previous OS versions before.

[image: Desktop & Documents Folders setting enabled, moving those directories to iCloud]

However, while I can *see* the symlinks to those folders in my home directory in Terminal, I don't see a folder or symlink for either `Desktop` or `Documents` when viewing my home directory in Finder. This wasn't previously a problem for me under Monterey, but seems to act differently under Ventura—assuming the problem isn't user error, of course.

### Work-Arounds

I can still use the symlinks from the command line, and can navigate there by using the iCloud mount in Finder. These are work-arounds, though.

I'm also able to navigate to the folders by using the sidebar. I was able to add them by navigating to iCloud and dragging each of these folder into the sidebar, but feel like there's something wrong with the configuration of Finder or the settings on the symlinks.

### Inspecting the iCloud Symlinks

Both ~/Desktop and ~/Documents show similar settings when inspected directly:

```
~> xattr ~/Documents
com.apple.icloud.desktop
com.apple.macl
com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags
```

```
~> ls -l@d ~/Documents/
drwx------@ 44 user  staff  1408 Jun  6 10:23 /Users/user/Documents/
    com.apple.icloud.desktop      10 
    com.apple.macl    72 
    com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags   42
```

### Question Summary

Why won't Finder show ~/Documents when it's perfectly happy to show other symlinked directories? What can I do to fix this particular issue so that those specific iCloud folders (and I suppose others I may want to link) are visible within my home directory when using Finder?

Comment: Try using the absolute path rather than `~`.  Finder is not the shell and likely don’t handle tilde expansion.

Comment: @Allan I'm not using tildes in Finder. I'm simply defining where the directory is (or should be) for informational purposes. Regardless of notation, it should be visible in whatever is defined as *$HOME*.

Comment: When you created the symlink, did you use absolute paths?  That’s what i was referring to.  Sorry, my question wasn’t clear.

Comment: @Allan I didn't create the symlinks. macOS does, as part of moving those directories to iCloud. I'm reluctant to forcibly replace them when they have special extended attributes that are likely required for them to work as intended with other OS features.